# How to show a part of chart labes

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have such data

```
data = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
   Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ragWk.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

> `<|0 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, ..., 244 -> 1, 250 -> 2, 251 -> 1, 254 -> 1|>`

If I plot it directly

```
BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

As you see, I cannot bear that dense labels. Now I just want to show `Range[0,255,10]`. Is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I don't know why data at 254 does not show up.

```
  Graphics[Inset[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {255, 
   155}], Axes -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, 155, 20], None}, {Range[0, 255, 20], None}},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 255}, {0, 155}}]
```

[image]